# Execute Transfer in Google Bigquery - PERMISSION_DENIED: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying the new 'Transfers' function in google BigQuery.

I am using the option: 'Scheduled Query'

It works with a simple query, but when I am trying another query that is normally working based on a view, that is based on a join between two tables (on table based on a google sheet shared with me) none of the more complicated Transfers I created are working.

I get the following error message:

Failed to start job for table 'xxx' with error PERMISSION_DENIED: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.

Is it because one of the source tables is based on a google sheet?

I tried to copy the source table to another table, but when I do this BigQuery automatically deletes this table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the view which queries Google Drive data. In order to resolve your problem you need to request [Google Drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3). Quoting directly from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#enable-google-drive):

> Accessing data hosted within Google Drive requires an additional OAuth
>   scope, both when defining the federated source as well as during query
>   execution.

In the documentation page linked above you'll also find ways to do this via command line, api and web UI.

Comment: I tried the webgui & gcloud commands to get access, but I get the restricted_client error:

Unregistered scope(s) in the request: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Request Details
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
openid.realm=
prompt=consent
access_type=offline
include_granted_scopes=false
redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/bigquery.cloud.google.com?id=auth <id number>
client_id=< client string >.apps.googleusercontent.com
ss_domain=https://bigquery.cloud.google.com
gsiwebsdk=shim

any Gcloud ClI ideas?